# Defining page direction dynamically - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, direction

I'm trying to set the page direction (RTL or LTR) dynamically on my Angular 5 project.

In **index.html**, if I write statically one or another in body tag or app-root selector, works fine.

```
<body dir="rtl">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

However, if I try to set dynamically, e.g using a variable called textDir, nothing happens (it keeps the standard value, LTR value):

index.html

```
<body [dir]="textDir">
  <app-root></app-root> <!-- I tried also <app-root [dir]="textDir"></app-root> with no success -->
</body>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  public textDir;    
  lang = sessionStorage.getItem("lang");    

  constructor() { 

    if(this.lang === "he"){
      this.textDir = 'rtl';
    }
    else {
      this.textDir = 'ltr';
    }
    console.log(this.textDir); 
  }

}
```

The `console.log` displays the correct direction, according to the conditional, but has no effect on `index.html`.
How can I do that?

Comment: The values in AppComponent are only available from `app.component.html`, not from `index.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no template binding done in the `index.html`. For this you have to make a root element inside your `app.component.html` like:

**app.component.html**

```
<div [dir]="textDir">
  <!-- rest of app template -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use document.dir in your app component contractor and it will set the dir to your html tag and can pass it with variable

```
direction : string = "rtl";
constructor() {
  document.dir = this.direction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

following [Mustafa saeed's link](https://medium.com/@mustafasaeed007/angular-localization-to-support-right-to-left-languages-7225a6c71eef), i wrote the following code in my translate function of mgx-translate switchLang().

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-translater',
  templateUrl: './translater.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./translater.component.scss']
})
export class TranslaterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'ar']);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  switchLang(lang: string) {
    const htmlTag = this.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0] as HTMLHtmlElement;
    htmlTag.dir = lang === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr";
    htmlTag.lang = lang;
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }

}
```

translater.component.html

```
<select #selectedLang (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" [value]="language"
      [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
      {{ language | uppercase }}
    </option>
</select>
```

as i was using ngx-foundation, which has inbuilt support for [rtl-ltr directions](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/rtl.html), i did not  had to use any more css..